# How to get dual monitor set up with NVIDIA Geforce GT 610

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce

So I recently installed a NVIDIA Geforce GT 610 into my Dell Optiplex 790 (running 32bit Windows 7 Professional) so as to be able to have dual displays. I installed card properly and installed the necessary drivers. The problem is that it doesn't recognize the second monitor and I am not entirely sure.

How can I make this setup work? Any help, tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** I had both the VGA and DVI plugged in the new graphics card

**Solution:** So I pushed the **+** button on my monitor and then my computer was able to recognize the display. It must have been on the wrong input. A silly error, but one none the less.

Comment: You are not entirely sure of what exactly?  Does this graphics card support multiple monitors?

Comment: Could you clarify your setup?  Are you using a single, dual-head card?  Multiple video cards?  What have you tried that's led you to conclude the second monitor is not recognized?

Comment: The graphics card does indeed support multiple displays, and I had both a VGA and DVI plugged in from the new graphics card. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: The second monitor when plugged in would show a black screen and say something around the lines of no input. And when I plugged both in the monitor that was plugged in via VGA would suddenly drop all content and just have the blue background that was on windows.

Answer (score 2):

The GT610 will drive two monitors simultaneously with little to no configuration. Connect a monitor to each of the VGA and DVI ports and they should both work. You may need to go to the Windows Control Panel, open the "Display" module and "Detect" your monitors and it should work.

To attach a VGA monitor to the DVI port you can get an adapter at Radio Shack.

To get maximum performance and video control from your GT610 you should install the NVIDIA Control Panel. Once installed this is a new management module in the Windows Control Panel and allows you to config and manage all aspects of your dual displays.

I'm just an NVIDIA fan. Not associated with NVIDIA, any reseller or technical support.

Comment: Just a follow up question, when we say 2 monitors, I guess it means extending the desktop not replicating the same screen like a splitter?

Answer (score 0):

[This KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976064) details the setup inside Windows 7.  There is a hotkey for use with projectors and multiple monitors to tell it to "Extend" your desktop.  Once you do this you should be able to enable the monitor in the settings if it does not automatically do so.

Also make sure your monitor is set to the correct input if it has multiples.  You may need to manually set it using the buttons on the monitor or try powering it off and back on again if it does not automatically detect the signal.

Comment: I think the monitor was not in the right input, because as soon as I pressed the "+" button on it it was suddenly recognized by my computer. 

Also the hotkey to toggle through display settings **Windows Button** + **P** for those who are interested.

Thank you Mike for the suggestions.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  Once I found that hotkey combination it's helped a lot, especially on some laptops that don't have the hotkey for display switching